# Is it possible to hide intermediate tensors on tensorboard graph plot somehow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I wrote tensorflow graph to fit rotation angles between original and reconstructed data. I tried to use verbosed names for tensors and named scopes.

Nevertheless, graph plot is totally unintuitive:

[image]

this is probably because all intermediate tensors in the formulas are depicted as explicit nodes in the graph.

Is it possible to hide intermediate or unnamed nodes somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The trick for getting a beautiful and understandable tensorboard graph is to use scope declarations. They gather things together and collapse cells together until double clicked on.

Put you optimizer under a scope optimizer and it will pull together your optimizer support connections:

```
with tf.variable_scope("optimizer"):
    opt = SGD(lr=0.2, nesterov=True, decay=1e-7, momentum=0.9)
```

Put another scope around your mode.fit command to pull together gradient propagation links:

```
with tf.variable_scope("training"):
    model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=nb_epoch)
```

Those steps alone really clean up a model. Then do the same thing around repeated units and any loss computation. Some good examples [and pictures at this link](https://medium.com/intuitionmachine/teasing-out-tensorflow-graph-mess-64cf5ece4b00).

Using scopes in this way all my tensorboard graphs look like presentation pictures of the architecture and one can doubleclick anything to descend into details.